# Google Chrome malware

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, malware

For some time, I've had malware in Chrome. This malware does two things:

1. Whenever click on the `Extensions settings` from `Settings`, instead of opening the list of extensions, the tab disappears.
2. It randomly opens new tabs pointing to stuff like "update video plugin".

I guess the malware not allowing Chrome to go into the Extensions menu, so it can't be removed. How can I fix it?

Comment: It's likely that the problem was caused by something other than malware, like an incompatible plugin or corruption, especially if the cleanup tool fixed it.  A helpful suggestion for future problems: when posting a problem, it's better to just post the facts and not bias the responses by speculating on the cause.  You lucked out that someone guessed correctly at the underlying problem.  Otherwise, you might have wasted a lot of time pursuing remedies for a malware problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome has a Cleanup Tool that removes unwanted extensions, plugins etc. It seems to work quite well, but then again, I don't have any malware.

https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/

Answer (score 0):

DominatorX's suggestion is a good point to start, however consider running a good antivirus/anti-malware software on the background at all times even if you managed to remove the current malware.

There are many products on the market, and what you choose depends also on your operating system. Personally I use [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/security-essentials-download) since 2010 and my computer seems to be quite clean, however from time to time, or when I notice suspicious behavior, I run the [ESET antivirus's free scanner](http://www.eset.com/us/online-scanner/). I was paying for the ESET antivirus and I am very happy with it, However I rather save the cost since Microsoft Security Essential is free for Windows.

Comment: Just as a word of advice, MSE provides **minimal** protection against malware.  Any other free (verified safe) solution will most likely provide much better protection.

Comment: @scriptHero: Do you have any factual evidence you can cite for your claim?